# gRPC connection gets cut after 60 seconds if inactivity

Tags: c#, docker, nginx

I have been trying to set up a gRPC API capable of streaming events to a client. Basically, after a client has subscribed, the server will use gRPC's "Server Streaming" feature to send any new event to the client.

I expect there to be periods of inactivity, where the connection should remain active. However, with my current setup it seems Nginx is cutting the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity with the following exception at the client:

> Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Internal", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. IOException: The request was aborted. IOException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 9 additional bytes expected.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: The request was aborted.
> ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 9 additional bytes expected.

The question is **why**? and how can I prevent it?

#### My setup

The API is built in ASP.NET Core 3 (will probably upgrade to .NET 5 soon) and is running in a Docker container on a Digital Ocean server.
Nginx is also running in a Docker container on the server and works as a reverse proxy for the API (among other things).
The client is a simple C# client written in .NET Core and is run locally.

#### What have I tried?

I have tried to connect to the Docker image directly on the server using `grpc_cli` (bypassing Nginx) where the connection remain active for long periods of inactivity without any issues. So I can't see what else it can be, except Nginx. Also, most of Nginx default timeout values seem to be 60 seconds.

I have tried these Nginx settings and various combinations of them, yet haven't found the right one (or the right combination) yet:

```
location /commands.CommandService/ {
    grpc_pass grpc://commandApi;

    grpc_socket_keepalive on;
    grpc_read_timeout 3000s; # These are recommended everywhere, but I haven't had any success
    grpc_send_timeout 3000s; # 
    grpc_next_upstream_timeout 0; 

    proxy_request_buffering off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_connect_timeout  3000s;
    proxy_send_timeout  3000s;
    proxy_read_timeout  3000s;
    proxy_socket_keepalive on;

    keepalive_timeout 90s;
    send_timeout 90s;

    client_body_timeout 3000s;
}
```

The most common suggestion for people with similar issues is to use `grpc_read_timeout` and `grpc_send_timeout`, but they don't work for me. I guess it makes sense since I'm not actively sending/receiving anything.

My client code looks like this:

```
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://myapi.com", new GrpcChannelOptions()
{
    HttpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler) { Timeout = Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan },

});
var commandService = channel.CreateGrpcService<ICommandService>();
var request = new CommandSubscriptionRequest()
{
    HandlerId = _handlerId
};

var sd = new CancellationTokenSource();
var r = new CallContext(callOptions: new CallOptions(deadline: null, cancellationToken: sd.Token));
await foreach (var command in commandService.SubscribeCommandsAsync(request, r))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Processing command: " + command.Id);
}

return channel;
```

To be clear, the call to the API works and I can receive commands from the server. If I just keep sending commands from the API, everything is working beautifully. But as soon as I stop for 60 seconds (I have timed it), the connection breaks.

A possible workaround would be to just keep sending a kind of heartbeat to keep the connection open, but I would prefer not to.

Does anyone know how I can fix it? Am I missing something obvious?

**UPDATE:** Turns out it wasn't Nginx.  After I updated the API and the client to .NET 5 the problem disappeared. I can't say in what version this was fixed, but at least it's gone in .NET 5.

Comment: Not sure this is an Nginx issue, looks like a client connection problem.  What setting do you use for the kestrel server MaxConcurrentConnections?
Try
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Limits": {
      "MaxConcurrentConnections": 100,
      "MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections": 100
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is an Nginx issue, looks like a client connection problem.

Your results look very similar to an issue I had, that should have been [fixed in .net 3.0 patch](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40180). Try updating to a newer version of .NET and see if that fixes the problem.

---

Alternatively, it could be a problem with the max number of connections. Try setting the MaxConcurrentConnections for the kestrel server (in appsettings.json):

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Limits": {
      "MaxConcurrentConnections": 100,
      "MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections": 100
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Did a quick test with those values (didn't set them before), but it didn't seem to help. At the moment I only have my own single connection for testing. 
I guess a good test would be to upgrade to .NET 5 and see if it's the same issue. I will try that tomorrow (it's very late here).

Comment: Tried to update to .NET 5 and the problem seems to be gone. It is possible I didn't have the patch. Alternatively, some other fix has been added since then.
I was certain it was Nginx. So thanks for pointing me in the right direction!